# How to grab edge version of cordova-android from github

Tags: cordova, npm

There is a bug fix in the latest unreleased version of cordova-android https://github.com/apache/cordova-android
How do I grab this version and use it locally? I found instructions for cordova-cli and plugman but not cordova-android.